# How do you create HTML files using Ruby Dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

## Problem explanation

I have a logic (if statement in my view file), and I shall move it to the helper. I found that there is a way to convert code in ruby file into a plain HTML as follows:

```
fileHtml.puts "<h6> Upcoming event: </h6>"
```

This works only for static code. What if I have an array and I loop through it?

### Example

```
module UsersHelper
def check_upcoming_event(event)
    <% if event.date > Time.now %>
        <div class="m-1">
            <div class="border border-secondary p-2 m-3">
                <h6> Upcoming event: </h6>
                <p><strong>Event Description:</strong> <%= event.description %></p>
                <p><strong>Event Start Date and Time:</strong> <%= event.date %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="m-1">
            <div class="border border-secondary p-2 m-3">
                <h6> Previously attended event: </h6>
                <p><strong>Event Description:</strong> <%= event.description %></p>
                <p><strong>Event Start Date and Time:</strong> <%= event.date %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
end
```

end

Now, how do I apply the element of an array into the HTML, is this how it is done?

```
fileHtml.puts "<p><strong>Event Description:</strong>" event.description fileHtml.puts "</p>"
```

I tried to do it in this way, but it is giving an error

```
module UsersHelper
def check_upcoming_event(event)
    if event.date > Time.now
        fileHtml.puts "<p><strong>Event Description:</strong>" event.description fileHtml.puts "</p>"        
    end
end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*I found something, which not exactly what I was looking for.*

---

Basically, it returns ONLY the last string inside the nested :div

```
module UsersHelper
def check_upcoming_event(event)
    if event.date > Time.now
        content_tag :div, :class => "m-1" do
            content_tag :div, :class => "border border-secondary p-2 m-3" do
                tag.h6 "Upcoming event:"
                content_tag(:p, event.description)
                content_tag(:p, event.date)
            end
        end
    else
        content_tag :div, :class => "m-1" do
            content_tag :div, :class => "border border-secondary p-2 m-3" do
                content_tag(:h6, "Previously attended event:")
                content_tag(:p, event.description)
                content_tag(:p, event.date)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

For detailed guidance for using the content_tag to create HTML code in the Ruby file, visit this [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag).

[image: Snapshot]

### **UPDATE**

You can use concat as follows, but please note only use with content_tag with parenthesis:

```
            concat(content_tag(:div, class: "col-md-2") do
                if opinion.author.photo.attached?
                    tag("img", src: url_for(opinion.author.photo), class: ["img-80", "rounded"])
                end
            end)
            concat(content_tag(:div, class: "col-md-10") do
                # another set of code block
            end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You put ruby into views to create dynamically generated HTML. You can put loops, if statements, any ruby code in there.

Name the file `<action>.html.erb` where `<action>` is the name of the controller action (ie. `index.html.erb`).

In the file you can use ruby with `<% %>` and print ruby with `<%= %>`.

Here's an if statement:

```
<% if event.date > Time.now %>
  <div class="m-1">
    <div class="border border-secondary p-2 m-3">
      <h6> Upcoming event: </h6>
      <p><strong>Event Description:</strong> <%= event.description %></p>
      <p><strong>Event Start Date and Time:</strong> <%= event.date %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="m-1">
    <div class="border border-secondary p-2 m-3">
      <h6> Previously attended event: </h6>
      <p><strong>Event Description:</strong> <%= event.description %></p>
      <p><strong>Event Start Date and Time:</strong> <%= event.date %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's a loop:

```
<% events.each do |event| %>
  <% if event.date > Time.now %>
    ...
  <% else %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You should generally reserve helpers for smaller bits of code. For instance, I generally include a helper called `amer_date` which takes a ruby Date object and turns it into a string formated like `3/7/2020`. It's one line of code `date.strftime('%-m/%-d/%Y')`, but I use it so much that it's worth using a helper for.

Comment: Hi @sam, thanks for your feedback. I am aware of the embedded ruby file (in short ERB). Conventionally, no logic shall be used in the view file (which is <view>.html.erb file and all of them supposed to be moved to the Helper files. I did manage to solve the issue. If you are interested in details, please clink on this link where my source code is: https://github.com/SarvarKh/Private-Events-practice/blob/events/app/helpers/users_helper.rb